# Modern movie where rich people can buy a personal assistant that sit in a small egg

Tags: story-identification, movie, artificial-intelligence

This is a modern movie and rich people can buy this egg with a personal assistant. It's an actual person in it (or a person's mind). I believe it can even operate a toaster.

I believe later in the movie, a person (or their mind) can be transferred to such an egg. As a punishment, they increase the speed of time inside that egg to make the person inside the egg bored to death, so to speak.

Comment: _//I believe later in the movie, a person (or their mind) can be transferred to such an egg. As a punishment//_ as [K Mo] said in his (or her) answer it wasn't the individuals mind but a digital copy of it so (as I remember it) the original individual was unaffected, the punishment angle you're remembering was used to coerce the digital copy into performing the tasks desired of it.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

This is not a movie but an episode of *Black Mirror*. The episode called "[White Christmas](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/White_Christmas_(Black_Mirror))".

> The affluent Greta (Oona Chaplin) has undergone surgery to make a "cookie" of her—a digital clone stored within an egg-shaped object. Greta's cookie wakes up, not understanding where she is, and Matt explains that her job is to micromanage Greta's life. When the cookie refuses, Matt makes her experience three weeks passing in what lasts a few seconds to him. She protests again, leading Matt to force her to experience six months of time passing. Greta's cookie then concedes from the boredom caused by lack of stimuli, and she begins to control Greta's appliances and manage her calendar.